# Conditionally set shortcut arguments in wix installer script

Tags: wix, installation, shortcut, wix3.11

I have the following WIX shortcut.

```
 <!--Desktop shortcuts-->
  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop">
    <Component Id="CMP_DesktopShortcuts" Guid="{guidblah}">
      <Shortcut Id="Shotcut_Editor_Desktop"
                Name ="Software"
                Description="Software Description"
                Arguments="$(var.CmdLineArgs)"
                Target="blah.exe">
      </Shortcut>

      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                      Key="Software\blah"
                      Name="DesktopShortcutInstalled"
                      Type="integer"
                      Value="1"
                      KeyPath="yes"
      />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
```

I set CmdLineArgs in my build script depending on which installer I am building. One of my build scripts has no command line arguments and hence sets CmdLineArgs to null.

I then get this error:

> error CNDL0006: The Shortcut/@Arguments attribute's value cannot be an
>   empty string. If a value is not required, simply remove the entire
>   attribute.

How can I conditionally set Arguments only if $(var.CmdLineArgs) is not null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) to conditionally compile a `Shortcut` element either with or without the `Arguments` attribute depending on the variable.

```
<?ifdef CmdLineArgs?>
    <Shortcut Id="Shotcut_Editor_Desktop"
            Name ="Software"
            Description="Software Description"
            Arguments="$(var.CmdLineArgs)"
            Target="blah.exe">
    </Shortcut>
<?else?>
    <Shortcut Id="Shotcut_Editor_Desktop"
            Name ="Software"
            Description="Software Description"
            Target="blah.exe">
    </Shortcut>
<?endif?>
```

Unfortunately there is some duplication here because a preprocessor condition can't be applied on the attribute level, elements are the smallest granularity.

The following is **invalid** XML:

```
<Shortcut Id="Shotcut_Editor_Desktop"
        Name ="Software"
        Description="Software Description"
    <?ifdef CmdLineArgs?>
        Arguments="$(var.CmdLineArgs)"
    <?endif?>
        Target="blah.exe">
</Shortcut>
```

You can get rid of some of the duplication by using preprocessor variables for the other attributes too, e. g.:

```
<?ifdef CmdLineArgs?>
    <Shortcut Id="Shotcut_Editor_Desktop"
            Name ="$(var.ProductName)"
            Description="$(var.ProductDescription)"
            Arguments="$(var.CmdLineArgs)"
            Target="$(var.ProductExeFile)">
    </Shortcut>
<?else?>
    <Shortcut Id="Shotcut_Editor_Desktop"
            Name ="$(var.ProductName)"
            Description="$(var.ProductDescription)"
            Target="$(var.ProductExeFile)">
    </Shortcut>
<?endif?>
```

The `Id` attribute is unlikely to change, so I left it as is for better readability.

Comment: Never tried to apply preprocessor at the attribute level. Strange that it does not work, I thought pre-processing involved basic string replacement? I suppose those constructs are part of the schema. I take it <?undef ?> also fails?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul The WiX preprocessor works on a higher level than simple string replacement. It first reads the XML using a standard conforming XML parser which would choke when a [processing instruction](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-pi) would appear within the attribute section of an element. Only after that it does its actual preprocessing job.

Comment: Yes, I thought as much based on your previous explanation, thanks for verifying. Too many things to test to try everything.

Comment: I had to change it to  <?if $(var.CmdLineArgs)="" ?> as even though it was null it was still "defined". Thanks for the answer, I incorrectly assumed there was no preprocessor after I tried #if #else etc without any luck.